# Android Facebook login without native app or dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am developing an application in which i want to login via facebook. I want to do.
After splash screen a login screen is there on which user name and password edit text. After entering the credential on clicking on custom login button the user should authenticate from face book in background. If the user is authenticated then he directly goes on next activity. Without open native facebook app or dialog or browser with new facebook SDK.

Please guide me if this type login possible and give your valuable suggetions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT do that!
Facebook SDK is there for a reason.
If a user will enter his Facebook credentials, in your EditText, that can lead to account theft.